# How to get Brew formula from the filename of installed binary?

Tags: macos, homebrew, install

I often use `dpkg -S <file>` on Debian to get the package name that installed `<file>`.

However, using `brew` I cannot find this option anywhere?

How can I obtain the Brew formula that installed a given binary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `brew whence` external command takes an executable and looks up the Homebrew formula from where the executable comes.

### Installing

To install the `brew whence` command, run:

```
$ brew tap claui/whence
```

### Running

To run `brew whence`, pass it an executable:

```
$ brew whence python3
```

> ```
> Executable                Comes from    
> ==========                ==========    
> /usr/local/bin/python3    → python 3.7.7
> ```

Or pass it several executables at once:

```
$ brew whence 7z git-shell lzgrep
```

> ```
> Executable                  Comes from
> ==========                  ==========
> /usr/local/bin/7z           → p7zip 16.02_2
> /usr/local/bin/git-shell    → git 2.26.0
> /usr/local/bin/lzgrep       → xz 5.2.5
> ```

### More information

For more information and examples, run `brew help whence`:

```
$ brew help whence
```

### Full disclosure

Full disclosure: I wrote this command.
It is not part of Homebrew proper but you can inspect [the code](https://github.com/claui/homebrew-whence/blob/master/cmd/brew-whence.rb) yourself.

Comment: Not a user of Homebrew as I prefer MacPorts, but this is really cool.  +1

Comment: Thank you. So, basically what your command does, is to go into `/usr/local/bin`, search for a symlink matching the supplied filename, follow the  symlink into `/usr/local/Cellar` to get the name of the formula that's in the absolute path, e.g.: `/usr/local/bin/ragg2@ -> ../Cellar/radare2/4.3.1/bin/ragg2`?

Comment: @Shuzheng Mostly, yes. It also honors `/usr/local/sbin`, and I plan to add support for Cask- and npm-installed executables.

Comment: You may also want to check out https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found. It provides a `brew which-formula` command, which may support not-yet-installed packages, too. (I didn’t know it existed until after I wrote `brew whence`.)

Comment: `brew whence` does not work for the keg-only llvm formula. The "comes from" column is blank. `brew whence /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.a` `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.a  (not a link)`

Comment: @strager Good idea for an enhancement. PRs welcome.